# LAMPP on Ubuntu - http.conf

Tags: 10.10, server, apache2, lamp

Hey, I've got LAMPP installed in Ubuntu and I want to get .htaccess working but I don't know how. And, yes, I have searched all over Google.

Cheers,

Comment: What do you need done with .htaccess?  Have you found it, but it's not doing what you need?  How far along are you in setting up your site/apache stuff?  Thanks -- we need as much context as possible to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

basically you need to enable rewrite module which is done by

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And also you need to have AllowOverride in your configuration set to All and not None

and in ubuntu the configurations are found in apache2.conf

Answer (score 1):

LAMPP should be configured to enable .htaccess already. If you want to be sure, check for this line in `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Your web-root is located at `/opt/lampp/htdocs`. I usually make a symlink from the project I'm currently working on (so that htdocs is a symlink to /home/fraekkert/Code/Web/myProject).

You should then be able to just create a .htaccess file in your htdocs folder and use it right away.

Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html for some reference on how and what to do with .htaccess.